# how to close any web browser using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble closing web browser using javascript. I don't just want to close individual tab but complete browser. I don't even want c# code.
Is there any way to achieve the same using Javascript?

Comment: I seriously doubt this is possible as it would present a security risk.

Comment: You can't. Imagine the security and usability nightmares.

Comment: Use of the search bar would have given you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That would give you control of the user's browser which is a security issue. Also, it ignores the fact that you should never be in charge of someone else's browser.

Answer (score 0):

No.

It is entirely impossible to quit any browser with client side code (if it was possible, it would be highly annoying for all users).

Even closing the current tab is subject to strong restrictions (such as the tab being opened with JavaScript in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

So you can't close the browser, but you can use `window.close();` to close windows opened by `window.open();`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What source are you quoting? And how does this close the browser?

Comment: @j08691... Google Chrome throws that quote.

Comment: That will not close the browser @j08691.

Comment: Right, that's basically my point. Which the other answers and comments have already covered.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. If it was possible there would be a big security issue.